# Recall String Array by asking user for its Name

Tags: java, arrays, string, eclipse, input

I'm writing a program that can grade multiple choice exercises for a class.

I wanted to store each answer key as a String array, and then have the user enter a String (the name of the exercise) which would be able to summon the stored String array. From there I know how to compare the stored String to the user's inputs.

I just have no idea how to take the input String and use it to summon the stored String array. Any tips?

thanks!

Comment: Use a 2D Array or a Hashmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using individual arrays to store each answer is grossly inefficient. What you need is an object that can store **values** which can be referenced by a **key** and a `Hashmap` provides just that. Study the illustration below:

```
//Declare your hashmap:
Map <String, String> myAnswers = new HashMap<>();

 /*
 *Put the values you want
 *The put method takes in two parameters, the key and the value.
 *The key represents the name you want to call this element by.
 *The value is the actual value (so to speak)
 */

myAnswers.put("firstQuestion", "Answer of firstQuestion");
myAnswers.put("secondQuestion", "Answer of secondQuestion");
myAnswers.put("thirdQuestion", "Answer of thirdQuestion");

//You can go on and on: key, value.. Just like we did up there.
```

If you need the value of any of these keys, just do something like this:

```
myAnswers.get(firstQuestion);
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Comment: This was the next step I wanted to build up to! Was going to attempt first with String arrays, then attempt with Objects. I may just skip to Objects now, with the help you gave. So the user, when prompted, can choose which object to work with based on its key?

Comment: Exactly! But in this case, the objects are called Hashmaps.. all you need to do is just to reference by the key.. It's suits your purpose 100%. If you still don't understand how the Hashmap works, read this: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this, it kind of all depends on your code design, but in general you can retrieve specific positions of any String[] by using a simple for loop (assuming this is a long test quiz):

class Grades {
   Grades grades = new Grades();

```
String [] test1 = {"A", "B", "A", "C"};

for (int i = o; i < test1.length; i++) {
//this will retrieve every grade at every array position in order for 0 to 
however long the array is.
grades.get[i]
}
}
```

Comment: That's helpful, but I was actually more confused about the input part. I have a long list of different quiz answer keys, stored as String arrays. How can I have the user input the name of the desired quiz, so that the program will summon the answer key that I want to compare to?